# Xamarin Forms ListView Programatic Refresh Not Stopping on Android When Page Loaded

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

I have Portable project in Visual Studio 2015 with a `ListView` that gets populated with some data via an API call through the following function `refreshData`:

```
async Task refreshData()
{
    myListView.BeginRefresh();
    var apiCallResult = await App.Api.myApiGetCall();            
    myListView.ItemsSource = apiCallResult;
    myListView.EndRefresh();    
}
```

`refreshData()` is called in

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    refreshData();
}
```

Everything is working fine except on Android where the refresh indicator is not stopping or disappearing on `EndRefresh()` when the page is initially loaded. The page is in a `TabbedPage` so I can go to a different tab and then return to this page and the refresh indicator properly starts and stops with completion of my API call.

Why is refresh is not stopping when the page initially loads on Android? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: This works perfectly fine when I run on iOS.

So far I've tried:

1. replacing `myListView.BeginRefresh()` with `myListView.IsRefreshing = true` and `myListView.EndRefresh()` with `myListView.IsRefreshing = false`
2. Using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {//update list and endRefresh})`.
3. Using `async void refreshData()` instead of `async Task refreshData()`.

Comment: try to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (//your code related update list view);

Comment: just tried, didn't work.

Comment: try to use only     myListView.EndRefresh();    ..remove myListView.Isreferhing=false

Comment: I've tried that as well. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: try a simple list without asyn and await . maybe async is the reason

Comment: I've tried already without async when building it out and it was fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135421/discussion-between-mike-darwish-and-derflickschter).

Comment: protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> myListView.BeginRefresh());
  }       
myListView.Refreshing += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
 {
    refreshData();
 };
void refreshData()
 {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (
    var apiCallResult = App.Api.myApiGetCall();            
    myListView.ItemsSource = apiCallResult;
    myListView.EndRefresh(););
 }

Comment: @DerFlickscter did you try above code

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, by my side, if I put the `ListView` page under a `TabbedPage`, it will refresh twice when the page is initialized, and if it is not under a `TabbedPage`, it works fine. What you mean then by "not stop refresh"? Could you please share us a minimal reproducible demo?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT When I mean by "not stop refresh", I mean the refreshing spinning indicator does not disappear.

Comment: @DerFlickschter, then how will your refreshing spinning indicator be shown? By default, I can't see any refreshing spinning indicator. Each time when you load data, how many items will you load?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT The refresh spinning indicator is built into the ```ListView```. When I load data it will be generally in the range of 0-10 items.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I can get this problem when I start ListView refreshing in the *Page Contructor* and stop it after the data is loaded. Sometimes (quite often) Xamarin.Forms `ListView` doesn't cancel refreshing animation.

I believe you faced with a quite common issue with Android `SwipeRefreshLayout`: it may not stop refreshing animation after `setRefreshing(false)` called. Native Android developers use the following approach:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(refreshing);
    }
});
```

Interestingly, Xamarin.Forms uses this approach when it sets initial refreshing status ([code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4d5a1f5482eeb43661d0ac972262e09c53e61117/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs#L360-L364)); however, it is not enough. You need a custom renderer:

```
public class ExtendedListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The refresh layout that wraps the native ListView.
    /// </summary>
    private SwipeRefreshLayout _refreshLayout;

    public ExtendedListViewRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _refreshLayout = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        _refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)Control.Parent;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == ListView.IsRefreshingProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            // Do not call base method: we are handling it manually
            UpdateIsRefreshing();
            return;
        }
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates SwipeRefreshLayout animation status depending on the IsRefreshing Element 
    /// property.
    /// </summary>
    protected void UpdateIsRefreshing()
    {
        // I'm afraid this method can be called after the ListViewRenderer is disposed
        // So let's create a new reference to the SwipeRefreshLayout instance
        SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayoutInstance = _refreshLayout;

        if (refreshLayoutInstance == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool isRefreshing = Element.IsRefreshing;
        refreshLayoutInstance.Post(() =>
        {
            refreshLayoutInstance.Refreshing = isRefreshing;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow MVVM Pattern

On your ViewModel you need to:

- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- Define properties like:

  ```
   private bool _IsRefreshing;
   public bool IsRefreshing
   {
       get { return _IsRefreshing; }
       set { SetProperty(ref _IsRefreshing, value; } 
       /*So every time the property changes the view is notified*/
   }
  ```
- Define the method that fetch your data, in your case `refreshData()`
- Toggle the IsRefreshing true/false when needed

On your Page you need to:

- Bind the listview itemSource to a VM property with the `SetPropertyValue`
- Bind ListView.IsRefreshing to ViewModel's IsRefreshing:

  `MyListView.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(ListView.IsRefreshing, vm => vm.IsRefreshing);`

[Here](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/krome/linking-property-change-notifications-in-xamarin-forms-or-wpfsilverlight) is a great article talking about INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Why has this answer received a down vote? This is how it should be done, even though the code shared uses an additional framework. But the idea is to make a one way binding for the `IsRefreshing` property, and make it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and set it to false after your code that updates your list.

Comment: @Elisabeth that's true, but I can confirm that this can lead to an endless refreshing indicator in a tabbed page. I have it inside a `Task.Run(async () => await //..` and changing the "IsRefreshing" bool property of the VM thats bound to the ListView will sometimes not propergate the change event to the View. What Ingenator described is as he said just a "MVVM pattern". Nothing more.

Comment: @Csharpest Beware when updating in a task. If you have run off the main thread or didn’t complete the work, it is when your property change will never propagate to the view. Use ‘Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread’ to update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
async void refreshData()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        myListView.BeginRefresh();
        var apiCallResult = await App.Api.myApiGetCall();
        myListView.ItemsSource = apiCallResult;
        myListView.EndRefresh();
    });
}
```

Apparently, there is no need for "Task" anymore.

If the error occurs only in Android, it's possible that it's just the way Android handles threads. It does not allow threads to change visual elements directly. Sometimes when we try to do that it throws a silent exception and the code action have no practical effect.

Comment: > *Aparantly you don't need of the "Task" return too.* Well, you probably need it, otherwise you would execute network call in the UI thread

Comment: You're right @NikolaiDoronin. It make sense. So the whole approach in my answer is wrong. It's not the best way to do that